# Mee6 py api not refreshing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use an api for mee6 using python for a discord bot which gets the xp of a user.

Here is the code with the client.run removed

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from mee6_py_api import API
from discord.ext import tasks

mee6API = API(670824141225590815)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def xp(ctx):
    xp = await mee6API.levels.get_user_xp(ctx.message.author.id)
    await ctx.send("Your xp is {}.".format(xp))
```

When I start the program, it works accurately on the first command, but every single time after, it shows the exact same xp number, even though I am gaining xp as shown on the site of the mee6 levels.

Comment: Did you do the pip command (pip install mee6-py-api)?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very late response but I hope it still helps someone. I stumbled across this question because I had the same problem and I believe I found a solution by looking at the github of the mee6-py-api. (https://github.com/hyperevo/mee6-py-api)

The api automatically caches your last request and just gives it out again on your next, to override this you have to use the argument `dont_use_cache = True`. The argument is available when getting user details, user xp or user level.

So this here should work for you:

```py
xp = await mee6API.levels.get_user_xp(ctx.message.author.id, dont_use_cache = True)
```

It would be the same if you are trying to get the level or user details as mentioned above.